# Using variables inside gherkin syntax

Tags: java, gherkin

I'm trying to write my step definitions for my feature file, and I'm having abit of an issue.

Part of my scenario is

Then the "CUSTOMER_ORDER_PAGE" is displayed

The step for this is

```
@Then("^the \"([^\"]*)\" is displayed$")
public void the_is_displayed(String arg1) {
    assertEquals(chromeDriver.getCurrentUrl(), arg1)
}
```

the CUSTOMER_ORDER_PAGE is actually a String in a separate class which i want to be called into the assert equals, but it keeps passing through the variable name instead.

Does anyone know a way of taking the string passed through the gherkin syntax and then using the value assigned to that variable inside the steps definition?
p.s ignore the chromeDriver stuff, it's just finding the current URL.

Comment: Share your current scenario to give us more context.

Comment: @javanoob: Could you please share the error you are getting? I am almost daily using such generic codes here, and may be able to help you, if you can provide me more details on the code plus the error.